# How to extract the first digit of a 16 digit number?

Tags: c++

I have this code right here that compiles just fine getting the first digit of a 10 digit number.

I am wondering how to get my code to get the first digit of a 16 digit number?

I have tried changing 10 to 16 in the while loop and my program does not count the first digit. Here is my code down below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Enter a number : " << endl;
    cin >> number;

   // cout << "Last digit is : " << number % 10 << endl;

    while(number >= 10)
    {
        number = number/10;
    }

    cout<< "First digit is : "<< number << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Write this one out. Take some random 16-digit number, and follow the logic in your code. What does it do? How can you augment your code to make it do what you want? Try writing out the number at each stage of the iteration to get an idea for what you want it to do.

Comment: The `10` in the code shown relates to the number being [base 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal), not how many digits in the number. If you were working in hexadecimal, you would not divide by 10 to get the next digit.

Comment: you should check if `number` really has the 16 digit number entered by the user. `int` has a limited number of digits. The cheaty way of doing it is reading the number as a `std::string`

Comment: It is quite unclear what you mean by "counting the first digit". Should it be "print the first digit"?

Comment: On a 64-bit system it might.  This is why I really like `uint64_t` type declares to make things clear.  Using strings for the numbers make this mute.

Comment: Yeah I meant printing the first digit of a 16 digit number.

Comment: This sounds weird, but unless you're going to do arithmetic on a number, they're usually easier to manipulate as a string. Finding the first digit in a string is easy. First digit of a number forces you to work your way through the number backward to find where it starts.

Comment: The code you have prints the first digit of *any* base-10 number no matter how many digits it has (subject to the limitations of the size of `number`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` has at least 16 bits. The exact size is implementation defined. Even with 32 bits the maximum value is `2147483647`. You cannot store a 16 digit number in an `int`.

You can store numbers with more digits than any integer type can hold in a `std::string`. Because just reading some string from the user and printing the first character would be too much cheating, at least you should check that the user actually did enter a number:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    std::cout << "max int : " << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << "\n";

    std::string number;
    std::cin >> number;
    for (const auto& c : number) {
        if (std::isdigit(c) == 0) {
            std::cout << c << " is not a valid digit !";
            return 1;
        }         
    }
    if (number.size() > 0 && number[0] != '0') std::cout << number[0];
    else std::cout << "invalid input";
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fY8zo6E7q)

Comment: Alright thanks for the explanation and the answer to my question. Your solution was quite helpful.

Comment: At first I thought there is a problem in case the user inputs an empty string, but it seems impossible to do so. Do you know if a non-empty string is guaranteed by the `>>` operator for string input?

Comment: @nielsen the user can enter an empty string, my code didnt handle that properly. Its fixed now

Comment: what if the entered string starts with "0"? you'd probably need something like `find_first_of`

Comment: @TylerV good catch. Simpler to consider any leading zeros as invalid input

Answer (score 1):

Changing 10 with 16 won't work at all, the problem is the upper limits of an `int` which is usually `2147483647`, inputing values above this will not work, meaning the digit will always be 2.

What you need to do is to use a larger type. You can safely use `long long int` which can take 19 digits.

```
long long number;
```

It's max value is guaranteed to be `9223372036854775807` at least.

Ideally, if possible, you should extract the user input as a string, it would be a much easier task to then extract the first character [as exemplified by largest_prime_is_463035818](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67272577/6865932).

Comment: does it invoke ub? I think `<<` will just fail and assign `0` to `number`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, maybe not.

Comment: [since c++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt): "For signed integers, if extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, std::numeric_limits<T>::max() or std::numeric_limits<T>::min() (respectively) is written and failbit flag is set" I also didnt know that

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 no need to thank me 

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well. I have tested this as well and seems to work fine except with the first digit being a 0 like largest_prime was talking about. But your effort was appreciated still.

Comment: @EternalNightmare01, glad to help, largest_prime_is_463035818 is a much better option, you do well in using it.

Answer (score 1):

Learning how to use <string> will prove very, VERY useful for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> //extremely useful 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string aux;
    string number;
    cout<<"Enter a number: "<<endl;
    cin>>aux;
    number=aux.substr(0,1); //create a substring of aux, starting from the first position (first argument) and getting only one character (second argument)
    cout<<"First digit is "<<number<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

if you need the variable as int, use stoi():

```
int num=stoi(number);
```

if you want to be sure the input has 10 or 16 digits, use size():

```
int size=aux.size();
if (size!=10) //or 16, whatever you want
    cout<<"invalid number"<<endl;
```

Comment: Alright thanks this answer was also helpful at finding the first digit of a number.